# How do I use a module and a script in the terminal command ocaml?

Tags: linux, bash, ocaml

I'm trying to run a .ml script, `test.ml`, using the command `ocaml` and use a module, `template.ml`, that I setup.

Currently, I know that I can run ocaml using the module by doing `ocaml -init template.ml` and that I can run a script using `ocaml test.ml`.
I'm trying to run the script, test.ml, and use the module, template.ml.

I have tried using `ocaml test.ml` with the first line being `open Template ;;`after compiling template with `ocamlopt -c template.ml`. Template is undefined in that case.
I have also tried using `ocaml -init template.ml test.ml` with and without `open Template ;;` as the first line of code. They don't work or error respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `open` command is only for controlling the namespace. I.e., it controls the set of visible names. It doesn't have the effect (as is often assumed) of locating and making a module accessible. (In general you should avoid over-using `open`. It's never necessary; you can always use the full `Module.name` syntax.)

The `ocaml` command line takes any number of compiled ocaml modules followed by one ocaml (.ml) file.

So you can do what you want by compiling the template.ml file before you start:

```
$ ocamlc -c template.ml
$ ocaml template.cmo test.ml
```

Here is a fully worked example with minimal contents of the files:

```
$ cat template.ml
let f x = x + 5
$ cat test.ml
let main () = Printf.printf "%d\n" (Template.f 14)

let () = main ()
$ ocamlc -c template.ml
$ ocaml template.cmo test.ml
19
```

For what it's worth I think of OCaml as a compiled language rather than a scripting language. So I usually compile all the files and then run them. Using the same files as above, it looks like this:

```
$ ocamlc -o test template.ml test.ml
$ ./test
19
```

I only use the `ocaml` command when I want a to interact with an interpreter (which OCaml folks have traditionally called the "toplevel").

```ml
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.10.0

# let f x = x + 5;;
val f : int -> int = <fun>
# f 14;;
- : int = 19
#
```